If $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=+\infty$, prove that $\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}[f(x)+g(x)]=+\infty$.
Here is my approach
If $L=0$, the result is pretty obviuos and I will suppose that $L\neq0$. From $f$ we can write, for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $x>\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In particular, considering $\epsilon=\dfrac{|L|}{2}$, the last inequality means
$$L-\frac{|L|}{2}<f(x)<L+\frac{|L|}{2}.$$
Now I will split in 2 cases.
Case 1: $L>0$. We obtain
$$L-\frac{L}{2}<f(x)<L+\frac{L}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \  0<\frac{L}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3L}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x)>0 \ \ (*)$$
The hypotesis about $g$ gives
$$\epsilon>0, \ \exists\,\delta_2>0; \ \ x>\delta_2\ \  \Rightarrow \ \ g(x)>\epsilon(**)$$
Let $\delta=\max\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$ be, combining (*) and (**), we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}[f(x)+g(x)]=+\infty$.
Case 1: $L<0$. This implies
$$L-\frac{-L}{2}<f(x)<L+\frac{-L}{2}\ \ \Rightarrow \ \  \frac{3L}{2}<f(x)<\frac{L}{2}<0\ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x)<0. $$
And that's the point where I got stuck, because I don't know how to combine $f(x)<0$ with  $g(x)>\epsilon$ in order to get $f(x)+g(x)>\epsilon$.
Could anyone please give me an idea?
EDIT: After Keen-ameteur told me that I don't need to separate in case and seeing that he wrote $|L|-1$, I started to think this way:
for all $\epsilon'>0$, there is $\delta_1>0$ such that $x>\delta_1 \Rightarrow |f(x)-L|<\epsilon'$. In particular, considering $\epsilon'=1$, the last inequality means
$$L-1<f(x)<L+1 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ f(x)>L-1$$
and
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}g(x)=+\infty \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ (\forall \ \overline{\epsilon}>0, \ \exists\,\delta_2>0; \ \ x>\delta_2\ \  \Rightarrow \ \ g(x)>\overline{\epsilon}) $$
Now,considering $\overline{\epsilon}$ such that $\epsilon=\overline{\epsilon}+L-1>0$ and choosing $\delta=\max\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, we can say that for $x>\delta$, we have
$$ f(x)>L-1, \ \ g(x)>\overline{\epsilon} \ \ \Rightarrow f(x)+g(x)>L-1+\overline{\epsilon}=\epsilon.$$
Therefore $\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}[f(x)+g(x)]=+\infty$.

$\forall M>0, \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta>0$ s.t. $\forall x > \delta, |f(x) + g(x)| = |f(x) - L + g(x) + L| \geq ||g(x) + L| - |f(x) - L|| = g(x) + L - |f(x) - L| \geq M - \epsilon$. $M - \epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily big.

Let $M\in \mathbb R$. Then By definition There exist $r_1,r_2\in \mathbb R$ such that $$ f(x)>L-1~~~~;x>r_1$$ And
$$g(x)>M-L+1~~~~;x>r_2$$ Now we have $$ f(x)+g(x)>L-1+M-L+1=M~~~~;x>\text{max}\{r_1,r_2\}$$ This proves the claim.

(Side note: I don't see how $L=0$ is more obvious than $L>0$ but anyway...)
NOTE: The following is unnecessarily convoluted. Correct solution mentioned at the end.
You can do all the cases in one go. Start with arbitrary $M>0$. You seek $K$ such that $x\geq K$ implies $|f(x)+g(x)|\geq M$. We wish that there is no modulus here, that will make our job easy. So, the main idea is for large $x$, we can ensure that, and after that it is straightforward.
Find $K_1$ such that $|f(x)-L|\leq 1$ for $x\geq K_1$. Find $K_2$ such that $x\geq K_2$ implies $g(x)\geq 1-L$.
Then, for $x\geq\max\{K_1,K_2\}$, we have
$$f(x)+g(x)\geq (L-1)+(1-L)=0$$
and so $|f(x)+g(x)|=f(x)+g(x)$, as wished.
Now, we want $f(x)+g(x)\geq M$. Take $K_3$ such that $x\ge K_3$ implies $g(x)\geq M-(L-1)$. For $x\geq K=\max\{K_1,K_2,K_3\}$, we get
$$|f(x)+g(x)|=f(x)+g(x)\ge(L-1)+[M-(L-1)]=M$$
and so we are done.
Correction: Remove entirely the part about $K_2$ since we don't have to worry about any modulus. The question is pretty straightforward.
Hope this helps. :)

I don't think you need to separate the cases, but rather just take the worst case scenario that $L\leq 0$ already.
In that case, there exists some $x_1\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)> -\vert L\vert -1$ for all $x>x_1$.
Now just use the definition of $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=\infty$, to find for any $M>0$ an $x_2\geq x_1$ such that $f(x)+g(x)>M$ for all $x>x_2$. In particular, can you show there is an $x_2\geq x_1$ such that $g(x)>M-\vert L\vert -1$ for $x>x_2$?
